# datadog replace or manually assign log value

Tags: logging, monitoring, datadog

I have a message like 'Service is running' that i'm not able to change, so in log Grok Parser I want to replace it to 'INFO | Service is running' or manually or somehow manually assign like `%{level=INFO}` .
Please kindly advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in a processing pipeline with 2 steps:

1. Set up a [`Category Processor`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/processors/?tab=ui#category-processor) with a rule that matches on the query `Service is running` and applies a new attribute to those logs with a value of `level:info`
2. Set up a [`Status Remapper`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/processors/?tab=ui#log-status-remapper) to take the status from the attribute called `level`

If there are other queries/patterns you want to use to determine the log level/status, you can add multiple rules to the `Category Processor` in (1), and you can map the `level` value to `info/warn/error` and any other relevant status value.